# Unable to execute sql query in async

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to execute the SQL query in async and want to return the result but it's not returning the data, not sure what I'm missing.

```
public async Task<string> AsyncSBSystemApps()
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                        a.app_guid as AppGuid,
                        a.name as AppName,
                        a.state as AppState,
                        a.created_at as AppCreatedAt,
                        a.updated_at as AppUpdatedAt,
                        a.foundation as AppFoundation,

                        s.name as SpaceName,
                        o.name as OrgName
                    FROM
                        apps as a
                    INNER JOIN
                        spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                    INNER JOIN
                        organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                    where s.name = 'system' and o.name = 'system' and a.foundation = 2", connection);

                await connection.OpenAsync();


                string result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar() ;

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try this query with SSMS? Does it returns any data? Also, ExecuteScalar returns the first column from the first row. What do you expect this code to return?

Comment: Yes I tried in SSMS it does return data, I need everything that query executes

Comment: Can I return in data in JSON?

Comment: First, you need a model class that represent the data returned by this query. Then, instead of ExecuteScalar you need ExecuteReader. Using the reader you read row by row the returned data and create an instance of the model class. Each instance should be added to a List of that class. Finally you can serialize the list into as json string with the appropriate library.

Comment: I'm aware of this, is there any direct approach where I get data straight away?

Comment: There is no _straight away_ mode to transform the rows returned by a query in a single string. Perhaps you could start to use an ORM tool like Dapper that will simplify a lot the transformation of the raw data in object instances. Still you need to serialize in json the result

Comment: Perhaps I should correct myself. It seems that something is changing in Sql Server 2016 about using json data. See this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you have Sql Server 2016 you can try to add _FOR JSON PATH_ at the end of the WHERE statement and then execute your current code. Curious to know if it works

Comment: Even if I run `FOR JSON PATH` I still need to implement instance of a model?

Comment: Why do you want to return JSON in the first place? Why not just return an instance of an object that represents the data?

Comment: @mason yeah I was just looking into that but an instance of an object works just fine.

Comment: So then you just need to do as Steve says - Use ExecuteReader and populate an instance of an object. Or use an ORM tool that makes it easier for you, such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [FOR JSON PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to maintain full control over the format of the JSON output , you could add it behind the sql query and deserialize json , the following is a example I tested

```
public class ResponseBody
    {
        public string StudioName { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> AsyncSBSystemApps()
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                    s.Name as StudioName,

                    c.Name as CityName,
                    a.Street as Street
                FROM
                    Studios as s
                INNER JOIN
                    Cities as c ON s.Id = c.StudioId
                INNER JOIN
                    Addresses as a ON c.Id = a.CityId
                where s.Name = 'Studio1' and c.Name = 'Wuxi' and a.Number = '101'
                For JSON PATH  ", connection);

                await connection.OpenAsync();

                var result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                 // Deserializing json data to object 
                var getModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseBody>>(result);

                //return ...
            }
        }

    }
```

As mason suggested , you could also use Dapper(**Install Dapper package** 
 ) to get the query easily like below :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                var queryResult = connection.Query<ResponseBody>(@"SELECT 
                    s.Name as StudioName,

                    c.Name as CityName,
                    a.Street as Street
                FROM
                    Studios as s
                INNER JOIN
                    Cities as c ON s.Id = c.StudioId
                INNER JOIN
                    Addresses as a ON c.Id = a.CityId
                where s.Name = 'Studio1' and c.Name = 'Wuxi' and a.Number = '101'");

                return queryResult ;
            }
```